# Definition for tiles in a triangle, given angles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am currently struggeling to find a suitable model that finds tiles over a map. The tiles are defined by X,Y coordinates. I need to list all tiles in the marked triangles.

Ideally we should represent partially included tiles, but it does not need to be 100% accurate, an approximation is also acceptable.

so given θ1 and θ2, find the function that can describe X, Y of square tiles included in the black triangles.

I need a model that represents X, Y values in terms of given angle and the size of the main square (orange in the example)

here is an example that deomnstrates the problem
[example model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74WU2.png)

the algorith will be implemented mostly in SQL, but any pseudocode will do.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please [edit] the question to provide more information. Do you need to know which whole tiles are in the triangles, or which are partly inside? I suspect that you want this for a computer program, in which case pseudocode for loops will be acceptable.

Comment: thanks for the hints Ethan, I edited the post, hopefully it is clearer now.